# Invalid MBR Signature found for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, bootloader, boot-repair

My dual boot laptop (Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7) suddenly stopped booting. The GRUB menu did not show up. I tried the utility boot-repair and it did not even show "Recommended Repair" in the small popup window.

The BootInfo summary was uploaded at: https://paste2.org/I7XU5F19

The hard drive I am trying to fix (or recover data from) is `/dev/sda`, a Samsung SSD 840.

From the summary:

```
Drive: sda 
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

Invalid MBR Signature found.

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================
Unknown MBR on /dev/sda

00000000  49 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |I...............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
...
```

Any idea what I should do to fix it or recover the data from it?